# How to complete scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm scraping this part of the code as part of a loop.

```
<div class="rcl-ParticipantFixtureDetails_LhsContainerInner "><div class="rcl-ParticipantFixtureDetails_Details rcl-ParticipantFixtureDetails_Details-datetime "><div class="rcl-ParticipantFixtureDetails_BookCloses " style="">Ven 00:00</div><div class="rcl-FixtureIconBlock "><div class="rcl-FixtureIconBlock_VideoIcon"></div></div><div class="rcl-ParticipantFixtureDetails_MoreMarkets ">95</div></div><div class="rcl-ParticipantFixtureDetails_TeamAndScoresContainer"><div class="rcl-ParticipantFixtureDetails_TeamNames"><div class="rcl-ParticipantFixtureDetailsTeam "><div class="rcl-ParticipantFixtureDetailsTeam_TeamName ">Athletico Paranaense</div></div><div class="rcl-ParticipantFixtureDetailsTeam "><div class="rcl-ParticipantFixtureDetailsTeam_TeamName ">The Strongest</div></div></div></div></div>
```

I have already took off data about the two teams name but I need also data about date and time of the match that I think is in this part

```
><div class="rcl-ParticipantFixtureDetails_Details rcl-ParticipantFixtureDetails_Details-datetime "><div class="rcl-ParticipantFixtureDetails_BookCloses " style="">Ven 00:00
```

This is what I've already built:

```
page_text = driver.page_source
        page_text = Selector(text=page_text)
        page_text = page_text.css('.rcl-ParticipantFixtureDetails_TeamNames')
    
        for match in page_text:
            teams = match.css('.rcl-ParticipantFixtureDetailsTeam_TeamName ::text').getall()
            row = {
                "Home": teams[0], 
                "Away": teams[1],
            }
            rows.append(row)
```

Any help?

Comment: Can you please share the url?

Comment: Here it is https://www.bet365.it/#/AC/B1/C1/D1002/G40/I1/Q1/F^3/

Comment: any help mate??